# How to write values of __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT in log file of POST request

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, logging

I want to write the value of __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT in log file. I have tried to write value of Request.Form.ToString() into log by doing so I got the values of __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT into logs. But I also got the value of __VIEWSTATE (which I don't want in my logs file).

Is there any another way of logging __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT  into log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
string target= Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
string args= Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```